# Reset Forgotten Restrictions Passcode (Updated For 2017)

Tags: iphone, ios

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the techniques shared work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can still make use of **iBackupBot** to reset the restrictions passcode. Before you would just reset the restrictions passcode by inserting a line of code, however since that no longer works you have to find the encrypted version of the restrictions passcode and decrypt it using a website (http://ios7hash.derson.us/).

Here's the source and step-by-step procedure - https://www.techbout.com/reset-restrictions-passcode-iphone-ipad-ipod-8365/

Comment: Has this been tried and tested before? Or even reviewed?

Comment: Yup, I tried and tested it on my iPhone 6s